# How to reverse this?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, reverse

i'm trying to get the encrypt reversing this decrypt but is really hard to do..

```
unsigned int decrypt(unsigned char *encBuffer, unsigned int encBufferLen, unsigned char *decBuffer)
{
unsigned int decBufferLen = 0;

unsigned char table[] = { NULL, ' ', '-', '.', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 0x0D };

unsigned int offset = 0, i = 0;
unsigned char encStrLen = 0, c = 0;

while (offset < encBufferLen)
{
    if (encBuffer[offset] == 0xFFU) // if byte is 0xFF then add 0x0D to new buffer and continue
    {
        *(decBuffer + decBufferLen++) = 0x0D;
        offset++;
        continue;
    }

    encStrLen = encBuffer[offset++]; // get string length

    i = 0;
    if ((encStrLen & 0x80U) == 0) // if result is 0 then decrypt the string by Xor 33
    {
        while ((i++ < encStrLen) && (offset < encBufferLen))
        {
            *(decBuffer + decBufferLen++) = (encBuffer[offset++] ^ 0x33U);
        }
    }
    else // otherwise
    {
        encStrLen &= 0x7FU;
        while ((i < encStrLen) && (offset < encBufferLen))
        {
            c = encBuffer[offset++]; // c = current byte, increment the index
            *(decBuffer + decBufferLen++) = (table[(c & 0xF0U) >> 4]);

            if (table[c & 0x0FU] != NULL)
            {
                *(decBuffer + decBufferLen++) = table[c & 0x0FU];
            }

            i += 2;
        }
    }
}

return decBufferLen;
```

}

This is what i got after some tests

```
std::vector<unsigned char> encrypt(std::vector<unsigned char> decryptedBuf)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> vector;

    unsigned int offset = 0, decryptedStringLength = 0;

    unsigned char currentByte = 0;

    while (offset < decryptedBuf.size())
    {
        if (decryptedBuf[offset] == 0x0D)
        {
            vector.push_back(0xFF);
            offset++;
            continue;
        }

        decryptedStringLength = decryptedBuf.size() - 1; // <--- to edit if encrypt works

        vector.push_back(decryptedStringLength); // <--- i'm not sure it will be interpreted right

        if (decryptedStringLength < 0x80) // < '128' Xor 33 http://pastebin.com/b18JfBFK
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < decryptedStringLength; i++)
                vector.push_back(decryptedBuf[offset++] ^ 0x33);
        }
        else // >= '128' Table
        {
            decryptedStringLength -= 0x80; // & 0x7F http://pastebin.com/THZjZJfs

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < decryptedStringLength; i += 2)
            {
                currentByte = decryptedBuf[offset++];


            }
        }
    }

    return vector;
}
```

Have you some idea about how to reverse it ?! I'm trying by 2 days but i haven't got nothing that works..

Comment: **-1**, too much code. You should post as little code as possible.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ntoskrnl have you some idea about how to reverse it ?

Answer (score 0):

`decrypt` is not one-to-one - many different cyphertexts may decrypt to the same plaintext. The easiest approach to a corresponding "encryption" function is to break the plaintext into chunks no longer than 127 bytes, and output chunk length followed by the chunk XOR 0x33. This way, you only exercise a small portion of `decrypt` algorithm. [<kbd>Working example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/824ab721ad0e57fe)

```
std::vector<unsigned char> encrypt(std::vector<unsigned char> decryptedBuf) {
  vector<unsigned char> result;

  size_t cur_offset = 0;
  while (cur_offset < decryptedBuf.size()) {
    unsigned char chunk_size = static_cast<unsigned char>(
        min(decryptedBuf.size() - cur_offset, size_t(0x7F)));
    result.push_back(chunk_size);
    result.insert(result.end(), decryptedBuf.begin() + cur_offset,
                  decryptedBuf.begin() + cur_offset + chunk_size);

    for (vector<unsigned char>::iterator it = result.end() - chunk_size;
         it != result.end(); ++it) {
      *it ^= 0x33;
    }

    cur_offset += chunk_size;
  }
  return result;
}
```